# Rearranging Drupal navigation menu

Tags: php, css, drupal

Good day.

I am trying to modify the navigation menu layout of a drupal theme. The problem is i'm not a coder, but can follow tutorials and understand bits and peaices.

What I have is a set of menus and sub menus. At the moment the sub menus expand below their parent menus. What I want is for the sub menus to expand but live below all the parent menus so it would look like the structure below.

How it currently looks

**Navigation_Menu_One**

Sub_Menu_One

Sub_Menu_Two

Sub_Menu_Three

**Navigation_Menu_Two**

**Navigation_Menu_Three**

What I want it to end up looking like:

**Navigation_Menu_One**

**Navigation_Menu_Two**

**Navigation_Menu_Three**

Sub_Menu_One

Sub_Menu_Two

Sub_Menu_Three

What I have figured out is that the menu system is built from the following class's

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="first collapsed"></li>
<li class="first collapsed"></li>
<li class="collapsed"></li>
<li class="expanded active-trail"> (The expanded Menu)
<ul class="menu"></ul> (the sub menu I want to relocate)
</li>
<li class="collapsed"></li>
<li class="collapsed"></li>
<li class="collapsed"></li>
<li class="last collapsed"></li>
</ul>
```

So what I want to do is be able to add something to the page that would capture the

```
<ul class="menu"></ul>
```

that appears below the

```
<li class="expanded active-trail">
```

and relocate it to below the last class or another div.

I understand I will need to do this using PHP from one of the template files with in the theme. Would any one have any idea how I would go about doing this. The theme I am using is the Corolla theme if that helps at all, but I guess it would be the same for any theme.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

It seems to me from your description that you should be able to achieve this without writing any code. Simply navigate to `site building > menus > navigation` and use the drag handles to move the sub menus so that they are underneath the desired menu item.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The submenus are expanded when I click on one of the navigation menus. I want this to still be the case I just want them to expand in a different area (Below all the parent navigation Menus).

In drupal (using version 7) I can only move them to another location, which in turn makes them no longer part of that parent menu. I want to still keep the expanding and contracting feature.

Comment: @Alexis It sounds like something you should be able to achieve with CSS